# Immigration extra baggage allowance

Tags: immigration, new-zealand

If I am immigrating from South Africa to New Zealand, are there any airlines that will allow extra baggage? Which airlines would?

Comment: Pretty much all airlines allow extra baggage for a fee, which will vary according to route and destination. Typically they impose limits on the size/weight of each item and the total amount per passenger. Oversize or overweight baggage may be classed as cargo and subject to further fees if exceeding airline max weight restrictions. You may get a better answer if you update your question with details of the airline(s) with whom it would be feasible for you to travel based on your closest airport(s).

Comment: It is probably worth contacting the different airlines directly.  When we emigrated from NZ we were told by a friend (travel agent) that certain airlines would allow additional baggage for free for migrants, however in the end it was cheaper for us to book on a different airline.  IIRC we also had to buy a certain fare to be eligible